# Strange behavior with Angular dialog

Tags: angular, dialog

I have a dialog in my `angular app` that works as expected the first time you use. It contains a bunch of checkboxes allowing the user to select which devices for the app to track. However, after the 2nd time I display it, clicking on the close button submits the data to the app, but the dialog doesn't close. I have to click close again. Then if I open the dialog again, I will have to click close 3 times to dismiss the dialog. Here is where the dialog is opened in the calling component:

```
     ngOnInit() {
          this.className = this.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];


     // start the spinner
     this.loadingSubject.next(true);
     /**
      * List of all devices is coming from an observable managed by
      * the DeviceManagerService. We subscribe (block) on that data
      * being returned, we can't build up the dialog of checkbox id's
      * until we have that data.
      */
     this.deviceManagerService.getAllDevices().subscribe((devices) => {
       this.dataSource = devices;
       console.log('devices are: ', this.dataSource);
       this.loadingSubject.next(false);
       this.dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
       this.dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

       this.dialogConfig.data = this.dataSource;

       const dialogRef = this.trackDeviceDialogComponent.open(TrackDeviceDialogComponent, this.dialogConfig );

       dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
           this.devicesToTrack = result[0];
           this.devicesToTrackService.publishIMEIs(this.devicesToTrack);
           console.log('IMEIs to track from dialog:', this.devicesToTrack);
       });

     });

   }
```

I can't display the dialog until I receive the data from the observable behind the device manager service which is why I have it built inside the subscribe. Nothing unusual about the code to close the dialog:

```
  close() {
    // Filter out the unselected ids
    const selectedDevices = [];
    /**
     * Loop thru array of deviceNames looking for every item that has its checkbox
     * checked. For each check, grab the imei associated with that object and push
     * it into the selected devices array which is what will be returned from
     * this to the caller, tracking.component.
     */
    this.deviceForm.value.deviceNames
      .map((checked, index) =>  {
        checked ? selectedDevices.push(this.deviceNames[index].imei) : null;
      })
      .filter(value => value !== null);
    const returnData = [ selectedDevices, this.dateTimeRange ];
    this.dialogRef.close( returnData );
  }
```

and nothing special with the button html:

```
   <button class="mat-raised-button " routerLink="/home" (click)="close()">submit</button>
```

So what happens when I open the dialog for the 3rd time is there is a long delay while it loads, then the dialog displays with a dark gray background. I click submit the first time and the dark gray goes away to reveal the map underneath, still with a light shading on top of it, then after the 3rd click the dialog closes and the `/home` routerlink takes me to the map.

Do I have something fundamentally wrong with my design here?

Comment: Since you mention `dialog displays with a dark gray background.` by the 3rd time you open it and so on. Which means there are overlapping dialogs/backdrops opened each time and hence the growing darker background and multiple clicks required to close. I think the issue is with unsubscribed observables from the previous runs as you are creating the dialog in the `subscribe` method. Try unsubscribing from `this.deviceManagerService.getAllDevices()` each time you close the dialog box.

Comment: yes, that was it. Thanks!